# Cannot uninstall numpy 1.21.2, RECORD file not found

Tags: numpy, pip

I encountered a problem while installing `pip install pytorch-nlp`.
The error is as follows:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  'c:\users\pcpcpc\anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.21`.2.dist-info\METADATA'

So I tried to reinstall numpy by running:

```bash
pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.21.2
```

But I get the error:

> ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.21.2, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.21.2'.

Comment: I had the same error, but also multiple problems when installing other libraries including an `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` where I had to enable Windows Long Path Support. After enabling the long path support, I removed every numpy file and directory inside the `site-packages` of the virtual environment and reinstalled numpy, which then worked. I'm not 100% sure the problems are related, but they might be. Maybe also numpy was installed for a previous python version which I didn't want to use for the virtual env.

Answer (score 79):

As [@Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886239/cannot-uninstall-numpy-1-21-2-record-file-not-found#comment125401354_69057471) suggested, you might have an incomplete installation of `numpy` in your `site-packages` folder.

1. Find your `site-packages` folder.

   ```bash
   SITE_PACKAGES_FOLDER=$(python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_paths()['purelib'])")
   echo $SITE_PACKAGES_FOLDER
   ```
2. Check for extraneous `numpy` packages from your `site-packages` folder.

   ```bash
   ls $SITE_PACKAGES_FOLDER/numpy*
   ```
3. [Trash](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli) extraneous packages.

   ```bash
   pip install trash-cli
   trash-put $SITE_PACKAGES_FOLDER/numpy*
   ```
4. Reinstall `numpy`.

   ```bash
   pip install --upgrade numpy
   ```

Answer (score 18):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

#### What worked for me:

- Delete that particular folder from the `site-packages`

  - Only delete the folder with the **version number** and not the folder that has Python modules and files
  - Delete that folder with metadata files matching the numpy version in the warning and error message in the installation traceback
- Re-install the package

  - `pip install numpy` just as you would do
- This works for both cases

  - global environment
  - local or project-related environment
- *Else you will have to delete that environment and create a new one*

Comment: My answer is a bit manual but kinda similar to the top answer

Comment: Dunno if it's the "right" way but it worked for me! Just blow it up and try again :)

Comment: This answer is the only one that worked for me , for anyone that comes later and doens't know where the site packages folder is: the path is in the error. these types of errors are why I prefer working on ubuntu or mint

Answer (score 13):

Try manually deleting the numpy files/directories and then do

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>
```

One way to find the numpy files is to run

```
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)"
```

For example, this prints out

```
/home/tink-user/workspace/.conda_envs/tink-payment-categorization/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

for me. So you can go there:

```bash
cd /home/tink-user/workspace/.conda_envs/tink-payment-categorization/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

then you can check with something like this to see which numpys are there:

```bash
ls numpy*
ls | grep numpy
```

Delete the numpy directories and try force reinstalling (`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>`).

#### Conda

This also happened to me in a conda environment after I ended up with multiple numpy installations and tried to manually delete them by removing the directories in site-packages. I had to force reinstall with conda (I think after manually deleting the directories for numpy): `conda install numpy --force-reinstall`.

Comment: What if anaconda isn't installed?

Comment: maybe `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>`

Comment: It didn't work. Gives the same error as the OP. Upon investigation, I found that there were two dist-info for numpy, one for each version in my site-packages. This happened after I had tried to upgrade numpy. Deleting the older dist-info fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with Ansible I had conflicting items of `docker` and `docker-py`. Only one should be present.

```
- name: Uninstall conflicting Docker Python modules
  pip:
    name:
      - docker
      - docker-py
    state: absent

- name: Install Docker Python module
  pip:
    name: docker
    state: present
```