# Error installing Tensorflow - RECORD file not found for numpy

Tags: python, numpy, record, uninstallation

I tried to install tensorflow and had an error with the install.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `numpy.`

> Cannot uninstall numpy 1.20.3, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.20.3'.

Comment: Did you try running the command it suggested?

Comment: Yes i try but the same error code came out 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.20.3'

Comment: I had the same problem, and the answer here solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69057471/3728184