# appearing error with "restarting kernel may needed"

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pytorch

I'm using pytorch and now I need to access tensorflow package. but it got the message:
" ERROR: Cannot uninstall numpy 1.21.2, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps numpy==1.21.2'.
you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages"

Has anybody been faced with this error?

Comment: Hi ! Could you refer this similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886239/cannot-uninstall-numpy-1-21-2-record-file-not-found