# Error upgrading pip [Errno2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to upgrade pip by doing:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And I got:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/VICOMTECH/bdacosta/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (22.0.4)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
WARNING: No metadata found in /home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-22.0.4.dist-info/METADATA'
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    WARNING: No metadata found in /home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
ERROR: Cannot uninstall pip 22.0.4, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pip==22.0.4'.
```

I've tried to solve as shown in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886239/cannot-uninstall-numpy-1-21-2-record-file-not-found) but I encountered the same error:

```
pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pip
```

I still get:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
WARNING: No metadata found in /home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    WARNING: No metadata found in /home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
ERROR: Cannot uninstall pip 22.0.4, RECORD file not found. You might be able to recover from this via: 'pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps pip==22.0.4'.
```

And if I go to the specified folder by doing:

```
cd /home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip-22.0.4.dist-info && ls
```

I just find:

```
REQUESTED
```

This problem also does not allow me to install or upgrade any new package. Any suggestion about what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due because there were two versions of pip in the site-packages.

In the folder `/home/mypersonal/path/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` weirdly there were:

- `pip-23.1.2.dist-info` (correct and up-to-date)
- `pip-22.0.4.dist-info` (root of the problem).

I just removed the second one and everything started to work well again, including installing new packages.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling your pip "raw" either with

```bash
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

or

Downloading the bootstrapping script from: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and running that.

Source: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#supported-methods